# Is it possible to set a default column value in PostgreSQL using an external non-SQL function?

Tags: postgresql, sql

For example, say I wanted to have one column take the row id and run it through a Python script which returns some information related to that number (random example).

Would I need to manually populate the database with this information, or is there some mechanism to do this from within the database?

Comment: Did you consider PL/Python?

Answer (score 0):

[PL/Python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpython.html) seems like the obvious choice. Here's a little [quick tutorial](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/99-Quick-Intro-to-PLPython.html) to get you started. This is useful for situations where you need the database to automatically perform some operation (e.g. trigger), or from a stored procedure and your language of choice is python.

However, if it's just a one-off operation to go over all data and update something, it's probably better to write this outside the database in a script and just run it against the database. Generally speaking, maintaining your code outside the database itself is better. You can more easily version-control it, run tests against it and update it as necessary. That of course depends on many factors so it's more a question of preference than something definitive. PL/Python wouldn't exist if it didn't have a legitimate use-case (and obviously it does).